# HyperLink in Java Script

Tags: javascript, java, php, html

I am currently using a program called finnegans that use a mix of JavaScript,PHP and Html, but the question in particular is this:
I have this chunk of code:

```
CentralMail mail = sender.getSystemMail( mailDestino, "Internal purchase accepted","<h4> Please confirm the list of asigned resources in "a link to docs.google"<br><br>Description: " + descriptionSVI + " </h4>");
sender.send( mail , accion.getTransaccionID() );
```

So the question instead of using that chunk of url i would like to use a hyperlink with a phrase that says something like "go here to confirm the list"

Sorry if i had any grammatical mistakes or something like that and thanks in advance
cheers!

Comment: To get the best chance at a timely helpful response, you should use the formatting tools available, particularly the code block button/markup.

Comment: Ok, add the hyperlink. What's the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what that code there does but it should work if you do

```
<a href="url"> go here to confirm the list </a>
```